# if statement on login page fails to continue if the if statement is met

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication, bcrypt

I currently have a problem with the following php code:

```
if ($result['username'] == $_POST["name"]) {
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(10);
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $hashdb = $result['password'];

        $hash = $bcrypt->hash($password);
        $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($password, $hashdb);

        if ($isGood == 1) {

            if($result['active'] == 1) {

                $_SESSION["login"] = $result['firstname']." ".$result['lastname'];
                $_SESSION["functionlevel"] = $result['functionlevel'];

                header("location:startpagina.php");
            } else {
                echo 'Account blocked or not activated';
            }


        } else {
            echo 'Password not correct';
        }

}  else {
    echo 'Username not correct';
}
```

I am using the [Andrew Moore bcrypt class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for hashing and verifying the passwords. 
For some reason my if statement seems to fail and suddenly stops after the second `if` statement. If this one fails it shows the password not correct option. But if it is true it does not continue to the third `if`.

I have tried different options in the second `if` like:

`if ($isGood){`

`if ($isGood == true){`

`if ($isGood !== false){`

`if ($isGood !== 0){`

But somehow none of these seem to continue if the statement is met.
It just shows the login page again instead of continuing to `startpagina.php`.
The login page worked fine without the bcrypt implementation and with just checking two md5 hashes against each other.

Can anybody help me trying to find the problem?

Comment: first typo   `$password = $_POST["password];` should be   `$password = $_POST["password"];`

Comment: where is $result['active'] set? You use it in an IF statement - but I do not see it defined anywhere

Comment: @NullPointer Fixed the typo. Somehow when copying and pasting the code here I made that error.

@TheShiftExchange `$result['active']` comes from the database. $result is an array containing the users data.

Comment: Put 'exit();' after 'header("location:startpagina.php");' It will prevent more issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $isGood is always going to be false - because you have not verified the hash correctly.

Change

```
    $hash = $bcrypt->hash($password);
    $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($password, $hashdb);
```

to

```
    $hash = $bcrypt->hash($_POST["password"]);
    $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($hashdb, $hash);
```

This is how I would write it

```
if ($result['username'] == $_POST["name"]) {
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(10);

        if ($bcrypt->verify($result['password'], $bcrypt->hash($_POST["password"]))) {

            if($result['active']) {

                $_SESSION["login"] = $result['firstname']." ".$result['lastname'];
                $_SESSION["functionlevel"] = $result['functionlevel'];

                header("location:startpagina.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo 'Account blocked or not activated';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Password not correct';
        }

}  else {
    echo 'Username not correct';
}
```

Comment: Finally figured out what the problem was. My `if` statement was working correctly(didn't matter which way). The problem was that it didn't executed the `header("startpagina.php");` which is why it displayed the login screen again. Now that I have fixed it I can finally continue..

But still thanks for your help. Your method is smaller than mine so I am using that one now.